# Корректное сравнение даты

Tags: php

Подскажите. В бд записывается дата с +7 дней от текущей. Получается, имею дату в базе `01/01/2020 15:00:00`, например
Сделал переменную для хранения текущей даты `$now = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");`
Пытался сравнивать напрямую через запрос по типу `WHERE expire < '$now'` - понятное дело, что не работает при определенных условиях.
Прочитал тут в одном из топиков..Создал переменные, извлек значение из БД и попытался сравнить как строки - 0 результата. Какие еще есть варианты сравнения дат ?

Comment: `strtotime()` обе даты и сравнивать 2 числа. А так-то, какой тип колонки с датой? И, сравнение `WHERE expire < '$now'` должно работать. Если не работает значит что-то не правильно делаете. Попробуйте так `WHERE DATE(expire) < $now`

Comment: @InDevX тип колонки с датой - VARCHAR..не срабатывает потому, что он выводит почему то результат на основе первых двух чисел..Дня и Месяца, а год игнорирует. т.е если стоит 10.09.2019 а сравниваемая 01.01.2020 то он скажет, что большая дата та, у которой 2019 год...читал об этом, говорят недочет

Comment: попробую по вашему методу..как приеду домой, отпишусь )

Comment: @steam.apk2 тип колонки с датой У ВАС - VARCHAR, а должен быть DATETIME или TIMESTAMP. От этого и не работет

Comment: @Alexus а в DATETIME я могу кастомный вариант даты разве записать ?

Comment: @steam.apk2 измените переменную $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")  и сравнивайте в запросе

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Помогли очень.. если бы можно было выбрать несколько лучших - выбрал бы все ответы ))

Comment: @steam.apk2 Добавьте ответ, что помог (желательно полный) и поставьте внизу справа галочку "общий". А насчет кастомной даты в datetime - после извлечения с бд можно что угодно с датой сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте UNIX TIME. При добавлении записи:

```
$name = "Some name";
$expire = time() + 604800; //1 неделя
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (name,expire) VALUES(:name, :expire)"; //Тип колонки expire - INT
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":name",$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":expire",$expire,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

При выводе (для MySQL):

```
$current_time = time();
$sql = " SELECT name,FROM_UNIXTIME(expire) FROM items WHERE expire >= :current_time";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":name",$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":expire",$expire,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$data = $statement->fetchAll();
```